# Rails 5 - Pundit policy for the new required model field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pundit

I want to change one `phone` user field to be required. When the existing user does not have this field set (did not have to provide a phone number beforehand) it should redirect to the `user_edit` page and display `Phone is required` message below form. I'm using `Pundit` gem for authorization:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Pundit

  rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :login_not_authorized

  private

  def login_not_authorized
    flash[:alert] = 'You are not authorized to perform this action.'
    redirect_to(request.referer || root_path)
  end
end
```

How to check if existing user have phone number and if not move this user to his EDIT page and display `Phone is required` error message below form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use something like this:

```rb
def login_not_authorized
  if current_user&.phone.blank?
    flash[:alert] = 'You must provide your phone number.'
    redirect_to(user_edit_path)
  else
    flash[:alert] = 'You are not authorized to perform this action.'
    redirect_to(request.referer || root_path)
  end
end
```